# rsync syncs too much files

Tags: ubuntu, backup, rsync, hash

I have the following directory structure:

```
/tmp1
  \_ file1.txt
  \_ file2.txt

/tmp2
  \_ file1.txt
  \_ file2.txt
  \_ file3.txt
/changes
```

With rsync's --compare-dest option, I want to sync all files into /changes that are not present in /tmp1 but in /tmp2. Modified files in /tmp2 that differ from /tmp1 should also be synced to /changes.

When I execute the following command:

```
rsync -acvu --compare-dest=/tmp1/ /tmp2/ changes
```

file3.txt will be saved in changes. But also file1.txt although the md5 sum of the file in both directories is equal!

Did I miss some parameters for rsync? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I find out that the files that shouldn't be synced have file permission -rw-rw-r-- others have -rwxrwxr-x. I can't find something about this behavior in relation to rsync.

Output of "ls -la" on both directories:

```
# ls -la /tmp1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1001 1001 4 Dec 31 15:00 file1.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1001 1001 6 Dec 31 15:00 file2.txt

# ls -la /tmp2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1001 1001 4 Dec 31 19:31 file1.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1001 1001 6 Dec 31 15:00 file2.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1001 1001 2 Dec 31 15:00 file3.txt

# ls -la /changes
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1001 1001 4 Dec 31 19:31 file1.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1001 1001 2 Dec 31 15:00 file3.txt
```

md5sum of file1.txt in both directories is equal!

Comment: Does `/tmp1/file1.txt` have a different modification time to `/tmp2/file1.txt`?

Comment: Yes, the /tmp directories are mounted LVM logical volumes. /tmp1 represents the origin LV and /tmp2 a full clone of /tmp1.

Comment: That's interesting, but it makes me unsure that you've answered my question, so I'll repeat it.  Are the the files' mtimes different?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought if I make a copy of something, it should be older than the original one. So yes, the mtime is different.

Comment: The other modification times are equal!

Comment: Ok, copy != modification... I think I got it... ;)

Comment: Again: **that is lovely, please answer the question**.  Are the `mtimes` on `/tmp1/file1.txt` and `/tmp2/file1.txt` different?  If it's easier, please cut-and-paste **into your question** the output of `ls -la /tmp?/file1.txt`.  It would also be useful to see the rsync command and its output side-by-side.

Comment: As mentioned above: Yes, mtime for both files is different. Please see the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `man` page for `rsync` notes that

> Beginning in version 2.6.4, multiple --compare-dest directories  may 
>   be  provided,  which  will
>                 cause  rsync  to search the list in the order specified for an exact match.  **If a match is found
>                 that differs only in attributes, a local copy is made and the attributes updated.**  If a match is
>                 not found, a basis file from one of the DIRs will be selected to try to speed up the transfer.

As I read it, that means that if it finds a file which is identical except in terms of attributes in both source and destination, the file isn't transferred from the remote source server; instead, `rsync` knows the files are identical, so makes the copy in `changes/` from **local** storage but sets the modification time to the newer timestamp of the remote instance.

To confirm this, look at the following output:

```
[madhatta@risby test]$ ls -la tmp1
total 36
drwxrwxr-x. 2 madhatta madhatta  4096 Feb  3 10:50 .
drwxrwxr-x. 4 madhatta madhatta  4096 Feb  3 11:01 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 madhatta madhatta 23150 Feb  3 10:59 file1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 madhatta madhatta   224 Feb  3 10:50 file2
[madhatta@risby test]$ ls -la tmp2
total 36
drwxrwxr-x. 2 madhatta madhatta  4096 Feb  3 10:51 .
drwxrwxr-x. 4 madhatta madhatta  4096 Feb  3 11:01 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 madhatta madhatta 23150 Feb  3 11:00 file1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 madhatta madhatta   224 Feb  3 10:50 file2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 madhatta madhatta     0 Feb  3 10:51 file3.txt
[madhatta@risby test]$ rsync -acvu --compare-dest=/home/madhatta/tmp/test/tmp1 tmp2/ changes
sending incremental file list
created directory changes
./
file1
file3.txt

sent 215 bytes  received 71 bytes  572.00 bytes/sec
total size is 23,374  speedup is 81.73
```

Whilst it reports `file1` as having been copied, the amount of data received (70-odd bytes) is in no wise enough to have copied `file1` (23kB), compressed or not.

Comment: Appreciate your explanation! Thanks a lot. Is there a proper way to exclude this local equal copies within the rsync command? Otherwise I will check the hash of all files in /changes and delete same files.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Glad you found my answer helpful (and thanks for the acceptance).